# req.sessionStore.all await not working in node.js with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, promise, express-session

```js
/*  current working */
export const userProfile = async (req, res) => {
  const loggedInUserList = [];

  const {
    params: { id }
  } = req;

  // await not working..
  await req.sessionStore.all((error, sessions) => {
    sessions.forEach((session) => {
      loggedInUserList.push(session.user._id);
      console.log("I want first", loggedInUserList);
      console.log(loggedInUserList.includes(id));
    });
  });

  console.log("I want second", loggedInUserList);

  const isUserLogin = Boolean(loggedInUserList.includes(String(id)));

  console.log("I want third", isUserLogin);

  const user = await User.findById(id)
    .populate("boards")
    .populate("followUsers")
    .populate("followingUsers");

  return res.status(200).render("user-profile", { user });
};
```

I want to get sessions from req.sessionStore, after this check user who have req.params.id is loggedIn by if user id in sessions. but await not working..
this is result

```
I want second []  

I want third false  

I want first ['6241c87a3e95f193789c9ae0'] <- this is user id  

true
```

(⬇️ I want result like this.)

```
I want first ['6241c87a3e95f193789c9ae0']  

true  

I want second ['6241c87a3e95f193789c9ae0']  

I want third true
```

for get like this result, I tried await. but still not working...

Comment: Mongodb methods return a promise only if you don't pass a callback. Use `const sessions = await req.sessionStore.all();`. This also means no longer ignoring the `error`

Answer (score 0):

Never use promise-based methods and callback based methods together. That means, either use `async await`/ promise based methods or callback functions.

Since, you are using async functions, using `await` is most suitable. Your correct code will be:

```
const sessions = await req.sessionStore.all();
sessions.forEach((session) => {
  loggedInUserList.push(session.user._id);
  console.log('I want first', loggedInUserList);
  console.log(loggedInUserList.includes(id));
});
```